# SQL Query to Count Rows when Two Fields Match

Tags: sql, count

I'm trying to see if it's possible to count rows when two fields are matching in multiple rows. I have a chat system that stores message history in a sql database.  I want to see how many messages were sent from User 1 to User 2 in a certain time frame (monthly). So here's my sample table of fields:

```
Sending User | Receiving User | Message Text | Time Stamp
User 1       | User 2         | Hi           | 08/01/2021
User 3       | User 4         | Hello        | 08/01/2021
User 2       | User 1         | Hi Back      | 08/01/2021
User 1       | User 2         | Bye          | 08/02/2021
User 3       | User 4         | Goodbye      | 08/02/2021
User 1       | User 2         | Hello Again  | 08/03/2021
```

So I'm looking for output like this:

```
Sending User | Receiving User | Message Count
User 1       | User 2         | 3
User 2       | User 1         | 1
User 3       | User 4         | 2
```

I haven't been able to get the desired result with a Count query with Group By statements yet.

I've tried:

```
SELECT Sending User, Receiving User, COUNT(Message Text)
FROM TABLE
GROUP BY Sending User, Receiving User
```

But so far that's giving me multiple rows for each user, so I have several rows for the same sending and receiving user combination. I'm expecting just one.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  And this looks like a simple `GROUP BY`.  What have you tried?

Comment: "I haven't been able to get the desired result with a Count query with Group By statements yet."... Which query? Please, add it to the question. The only way to count rows is to count them.

Comment: Edited question with one query I've tried.  I've tried other variations with count statements and items in the GROUP BY statement.

Comment: `GROUP BY X, Y` will ***not*** give multiple rows for the same combinations of X and Y.  Either the values are not identical (spelling errors, varying amounts of white space, etc), or that's not the query you ran.

Comment: Two points: 1) Why are you storing the word *user* in your user columns? The column name clearly indicates that they're users, and you should be storing only the user ID, not the expression *user*. It clarifies things, and avoids the possibility of typos (*User*, *user* and *usre*, for example, or an extra space between *User* and the ID value. 2) Please read the description of tags when using them, especially when you're new here. The SQL tag suggests **strongly** that when using it, you also include a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as functionality and syntax differs between them.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired results don't take into account any particular date range, but your example query gives *exactly* your desired results:

```
select sendinguser, ReceivingUser, Count(*) MessageCount
from t
where timestamp between '20210801' and '20210831'
group by sendinguser,ReceivingUser
order by sendinguser
```

See [example DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a4dbf721e6b2f470cc5f33bf341d622c)

Comment: Interesting.  My output is still creating multiple rows with the same User 1 and User 2 combination but different Message Counts. I'm not understanding why.

Comment: I think I figured it out. I was running some format changes on the User fields and after @MatBailie's post I learned that the user fields were not actually identical like I assumed. Thanks.